# How to redirect output to file that has slash in name

Tags: bash, redirection, bash-scripting, filenames

I want to create a file named `./https://www.example.com`, but the following doesn't work:

```
[ ~]$ URL="https://www.example.com"
[ ~]$ echo "Hello!" >"$URL"
bash: https://www.example.com: No such file or directory
```

How can I tell bash I want a filename with slashes in it, and that I'm not trying to look into a different (nonexistent) directory?

Comment: You can't.  The slash is one of only two characters that are not allowed in Unix file names.  (The other is NUL.).

Comment: I just tried it on Ubuntu 12.04 and that allows for back-slashes in file names...  So the real question is why one would want a file with a name that is a URL, and if that reason is trivial, one could easily substitute the forward slashes with backslashes...

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make URL a file, it makes it a variable (via assignment):

```
$ URL="https://www.example.com"
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html

Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, $URL is a variable. When you execute `command [args] >filedescriptor`, filedescriptor is taken as the name of the file. E.g. `echo hello, world! > hello.txt` will create a file with the name hello.txt and put "hello,world!" in it. In this case, I wanted a file whose name was `https://www.example.com`. However, as @John1024 points out, this is not possible because "/" is not a valid character in a filename.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to remap certain special characters, because '/' just can't be in a valid POSIX filename.

Try this:

```
FILENAME="$(echo "$URL" | tr '//:?+' '_')"
echo "Hello!" >"$FILENAME"
```